# Windows 10 always warns about disconnected network drive, even if it is actually connected

Tags: networking, nas, mapped-drive, windows-10-v1903

**tl;dr:** *Each time system starts, Windows 10 1903 produces a false alert and status about network location not being connected. And does not update this status after location is actually connected. Is there anything I can do with this or do I have to learn to live with this?*

---

I have a brand new Windows 10 1903. Right after installing it, I have mapped one of my network locations (my NAS) as N: drive, checking the checkbox to re-map it again upon each system start.

Each time I start the system I am getting an Action Center warning that some of my network drives were not mapped correctly. It is followed by This PC window showing not connected network drive:

[image]

The thing is that this particular network is actually connected. All I have to do is to double-click the above icon and I have uninterrupted access to all its contents in a matter of millisecond.

It seems that, for some reason, Windows 10 is not updating status of mapped drive (and Action Center message) whenever given network drive is actually connected.

Is there anyway to deal with this issue? Having it each time system starts is a bit annoying.

Maybe the problem is with the time? Maybe there's a way to delay moment Windows tries to map this network drive just a few seconds and problem will be resolved? Or -- is there any way to force Windows 10 to update network mapped drive status?

This problem started when I migrated my system from Windows 7 to Windows 10. When I was using Windows 7 (for about ten years) with the same NAS, I had no issues with this.

A warning about not connected mapped network drive was only issued when that particular network was really and truly not available, i.e. when connecting my PC to some public WiFi network instead of local home network.

Comment: It may sound silly but have you tried to remove and add it again? If the same problem then you be in the right track about the timing.

Comment: Strongly related (your question and the linked question came up when searching - not sure if a command-line fix every time you restart is an acceptable fix): [Can a mapped network drive be reconnected from the command line?](https://superuser.com/q/52595/581487)

Comment: If take the idea from linked question and post an answer here with a proposal of writing a simple batch file having this `pushd` command and then adding that batch file to an autostart then I'll be happy to upvote and accept your answer. I no longer have this problem, so I cannot verify whether this (or user931000's) idea works.

Comment: Ah, I meant to say that the fix that worked for me was [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/236972/581487) by [Claus Melander](https://superuser.com/users/64449/claus-melander) - using `Start /min explorer t:\` then `Taskkill /fi "windowtitle eq T_drive*"` - which worked when I had the same situation as you have in your answer. I guess it'd be better for me to flag this question as a duplicate of the linked one instead of posting my own answer here, maybe?